# Ist »gar nichts« eine Steigerung von »nichts«?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice

Ist *gar nichts* eine Steigerung von *nichts,* oder bedeutet es genau das gleiche?

Comment: *Steigerung* ist ziemlich sicher nicht das richtige Wort - Das würde im grammatikalischen Sinne des Wortes auf Komparativ oder Superlativ hinweisen, und das ist es sicher nicht. [Aussage-]*Verstärkung* passt hier wesentlich besser.

Comment: Zumindest im süddeutschen Sprachgebrauch wird der Modalpartikel "gar" gerne noch durch ein zusätzliches "rein" betont: "Es geht dich *rein gar nichts* an..."

Comment: @RalphLindnerRalphGL: Das gilt nicht nur in Süddeutschland.

Comment: @RalphLindnerRalphGL: Ich hätte das jetzt eher in Norddeutschland vermutet. Im Süden (Franken) ist mir dagegen "*überhaupt* gar nix" schon öfters begegnet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. nein
2. nein

Das ist weder eine Steigerung, noch bedeutet es dasselbe.

Steigerungen gibt es nur bei Adjektiven und Adverbien. (Bei vielen, aber nicht allen Adjektiven, und bei einigen wenigen Adverbien.)

> Adjektiv:
>
> - Positiv: Eva ist **schön**.
> - Komparativ: Eva ist **schöner**.
> - Superlativ: Eva ist **am schönsten**.
>
> Adverb:
>
> - Positiv: Das passiert **oft**.
> - Komparativ: Das passiert **öfter**.
> - Superlativ: Das passiert **am öftesten**.
>     (Der Superlativ von »oft« ist nicht im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum verbreitet)

Andere Wortarten können nicht gesteigert werden. Das Wort »nichts« ist aber weder ein Adjektiv, noch ein Adverb, sondern ein Pronomen (ein Indefinitpronomen). Daher kann es nicht gesteigert werden. (Die Formen »*nichtser*« und »*am nichtsesten*« sind falsch)

---

Das Wort »*gar*« ist hier eine [Modalpartikel](https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=modalpartikel). Solche Partikel ändern die grundlegende Aussage eines Satzes nicht, sie verändern aber den Ausdruck, sie tönen also die Stimmung des Satzes ab (daher kommt auch der alternative Name »Abtönungspartikel«). Diese Veränderung ist meist eine Verstärkung der Aussage, vermutlich hast du das mit »Steigerung« gemeint. (Der Ausdruck »Steigerung» ist aber anders definiert, siehe oben, und daher falsch.)

> Das war jetzt **aber** schnell.
>   Du bist **ja** schon wach.
>   Hole dir **doch** selber etwas!
>   Das mag ich **gar** nicht.

Die fett hervorgehobenen Wörter sind Beispiele für Modalpartikel. Modalpartikel kann man immer ersatzlos weglassen, ohne dass die Grundaussage des Satzes verändert wird. Aber die Ungeduld, der Nachdruck, das Staunen usw., all das verschwindet wenn man eine Modalpartikel weglässt:

> Das war jetzt schnell.
>   Du bist schon wach.
>   Hole dir selber etwas!
>   Das mag ich nicht.

Modalpartikel kommen im Deutschen sehr häufig vor, in fast allen anderen Sprachen sind sie entweder selten (z.B. Französisch) oder existieren gar nicht (z.B. Englisch). Daher kann man Modalpartikel auch nicht ins Englische übersetzen (man lässt sie meist ganz einfach weg).

Comment: Dass Englisch keine Modal**partikel** hat, ist so wohl richtig. Im konkreten Fall gibt es aber eine direkte Ubersetzbarkeit mit einem *Modaladverb* - "Gar nichts" übersetzt sich dann zu "absolutely nothing". Ähnliche Formen gibt es auch mit "certainly" oder "probably".

Comment: Hervorragende Antwort. Reich an Modalpartikeln ist übrigens Mandarin!

Answer (score 13):

*Gar* ist definiert als *sehr*, *ganz*, *vollkommen*, *überhaupt*. Also, ja, auch wenn man theoretisch "nichts" nicht steigern kann, ist "gar nichts" zumindest eine Steigerung im Sinne der Betonung.

Angemerkt sei noch, dass man nicht selten das Folgende hört, dem die Betonung deutlich zu entnehmen ist:

> nichts, aber auch gar nichts

Answer (score 1):

Kleine Ergänzung: Bei spottendem Sprachgebrauch ist eine Steigerung von *nichts* durchaus möglich.

> Und was hat er geleistet während seiner Amtszeit? Weniger als nichts.

**Zur Frage**

*Nichts* ist neutral, *gar nichts* beinhaltet eine Wertung.

Beispiele:

> »Was hat er seinen Kindern aus dem Urlaub mitgebracht?«
>   »Gar nichts.«
>   *(enttäuschend, nicht mal eine Kleinigkeit)*
>   *(Vater: »10 Tage Nordpol, was soll ich da mitbringen?«)*
>
> »Was hat der Chef zur Nichtverlängerung deines Vertrages erklärt?«
>   »Gar nichts!«
>   *(starkes Stück, eine Erläuterung, vielleicht eine Entschuldigung wurde erwartet)*
>
> »Hat der Arzt etwas in deinem Blut gefunden?«
>   »Gar nichts!«
>   *(ist das nicht schön, ich bin weniger krank als gedacht)*
>
> »Warum jetzt diese Aufregung, ich habe [doch] gar nichts dagegen!«
>   *(das Theater könnt ihr euch sparen, ihr irrt euch)*
>
> »Rudolf K., der so *gar* nichts von einem Buddha an sich hat.«
>   *(Mensch, ist der mager!)*

Comment: Ds hätte wohl eher ein Kommentar werden sollen...

Comment: Das mit der Wertung ist Unfug. Am deutlichsten in den letzten 2 Beispielen, aber auch biem Arzt kann das Fehlen dessen, was man im Blut gesucht hat, bedeuten, dass es die üblere von zwei Alternativen ist oder es ist ungewiss, was jetzt das Leiden verursacht und der schlechtere Fall, als eine therapierbare Erkrankung.

Comment: @user unknown: Blut: Der Sprecher freut sich, dass nichts gefunden wurde, es mag ihm Beweis sein, dass seine Krankheit eingebildet war. Ob seine Freude berechtigt ist, ist eine andere Frage. Vorletztes Beispiel: Unmut über die Fehleinschätzung der anderen. Letztes Beispiel: Ironie.

Comment: Blut: "Der Arzt:sagte, ich habe wohl eine X (Lappalie) oder Y (schwerer Fall). X ließe sich rasch mit einem Bluttest abklären." (Hier Deine 2 Sätze). Die Betonung wäre eine andere, woraus folgt, dass es der Kontext ist, der die Bewertung macht, nicht das Wort "gar". Ähnlich im Aufregungsfall. Sprich das aus und dann mit gleicher Betonung ohne "gar" - gleiche Bedeutung. Das "gar" ist nur eine Bekräftigung der immer schon gegebenen Bewertung. Beim Buddhabeispiel desgleichen.